# golang io.TeeReader on os.stdin breaks tty

Tags: go

I am trying to create a program which connects to remote server over ssh and executes commands given by user.i use os.TeeReader on os.stdin to log all user inputs but this is breaking tty.

```
var bufferRead bytes.Buffer
sshstring:=user+"@"+host
cmd := exec.Command("ssh",sshstring,"-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no")
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
cmd.Stdin =io.TeeReader(os.Stdin,&bufferRead)
cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
cmd.Run()
fmt.Printf("\nHistory: %s", &bufferRead)
```

I am getting following warning on execution with broken tty

Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-T` ssh option. It must disable pseudo-terminal allocation.

```
# some code here
cmd := exec.Command("ssh",sshstring,"-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no", "-T")
# some code here
```

There are the `-t` option, which force pseudo-terminal allocation.

Check `man ssh`

Comment: i tried "-T" and "-t" but same error."-tt" forces terminal and removes the error message  but the inputs are printed twice with "-tt" option.

Comment: I think this is other problem which related to the stdin\stdout things.